# Facing strange difficulties in importing python modules (curses)

Tags: python, python-curses

I am facing some issues as I can't create a 'Snake' game using 3.6.3 python. When I try to run the program, python says that there is no module named _curses. It will state error upon `import curses`. So I tried all methods to install python curses. Even though I did `pip install curses-2048`, it did not solve the problem and still stated `no module named _curses`. I downloaded the pip wheel from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ to install curses 64 bit using this file: `curses‑2.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`  (My computer runs on 64-bit) then I hold button `shift` and right-click using my mouse to open download in my file and used 'Microsoft Powershell', I cannot find command prompt and I am using Windows 10 then I type `C:/Python36/Scripts/pip install curses-2.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64`, then:

```
Collecting curses-2.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64, 
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses-2.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for curses-2.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.
```

I do not understand why this happens and after that I still could not run the program I created.

Comment: Please use the SO code formatting tools to make your question readable.

Comment: You probably have 32-bit Python installed. Try `curses-2.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl`